# How do you interpret SQL Server Execution Plan results

Tags: sql-server, indexing, execution-time

A page on my site is running slow.  I have determined it is due to the query below:

```html
select distinct top 500 j.correlationid, j.timestamp
from jobs as j
inner join status as s
on j.statusid = s.id
inner join tasks as t
on j.taskid = t.id
inner join processes as p
on t.processid = p.id
where j.viewable = 1
and p.[group] = 'SapDocument'
and s.name in ('Dead', 'Process Complete') 
order by j.timestamp desc
```

I have run estimated execution plan, but am not sure how to interpret.  I am hopeful someone can help me interpret.  I am thinking I may need an index somewhere.  Thanks so much for any tips!

[image]

Comment: This is a huge topic.  For the beginner, I would encourage you to look for items with the highest cost, and then items connected with the thickest line.

Comment: There are tutorials and entire books all over the place for this. "How do I interpret execution plans?" is a terrible question for this site.

Comment: Have a look at this question

[How to read an execution plan in SQL Server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server